# Sum of a two dimensional array calling a function

Tags: c

I'm trying to creates a program that finds the sum of a single two dimensional array by calling a function called sum. However I'm running into an error with a missing { however i'm unsure where this goes?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int s[3][4])
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int s[3][4], c, r, sum = 0;

for (r = 0; r <= 2; r++)
{
    for (c = 0; c <= 3; c++)
    {
        printf("Enter value for s[%d][%d]: ", r, c);
        scanf("%d", &s[r][c]);
    }
}
printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum(s[3][4]);
return 0;
}

int sum (int s[3][4])
{
for (r = 0; r <= 2; r++)
{
    for (c = 0; c <= 3; c++)
    {
        sum = s[r][c] + sum;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There's a semicolon missing between the function declaration and the definition of `main()`.

Comment: Your compiler should point you near the problematic location. Read the message carefully, then check your code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There are many more errors and I made an answer listing all errors. If you can reopen, I can post it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I am facing more issues then just a semicolon missing and I can't seem to find the overall problem why the program won't work.

Comment: @SagarV: You're right that there are a number of other problems other than the missing semicolon after the function declaration and before `int main(…)`.  And there some stylistically bad coding choices (`for (r = 0; r <= 2; r++)` instead of the idiomatic `for (r = 0; r < 3; r++)`, for example).  But I'm not sure that this warrants reopening the question.

Comment: @Bill: when you have problems getting code to compile, you should show us the compilation errors you are getting.  The missing `{` was actually a missing `;` — though a `{` would be another character that could appear at that point.  When you have compilation errors, identify the cause of the first, fix it, and try a recompilation.  Rinse, repeat until you get the code compiling.  As you gain experience, you'll realize which errors are a consequence of an earlier (now fixed) error and which are independent errors and you may fix multiple errors with a single compilation attempt.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wish it would reopen. I made detailed errors list and correction and did lot of typing. All is waste now. :-(

Comment: AFAIK, I don't have unilateral reopen privileges.  I can wield Mjölnir to close as a duplicate unilaterally, but there need to be other people to reopen. Also, because I'm a close voter, I don't think I can vote to reopen — unless perhaps the question is edited.

Comment: I'd just like to say thanks fir all the help, with your guys help I was able to complete it! @MohitYadav

Comment: @SagarV: We are not a debugging service. If a question has too many problems, drop a comment and close as "no specific problem" or "too broad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you cannot use `sum` as a function name because it is a predefined function. And your code has some minor syntax mistakes. Here is some fixed code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sumx(int s[3][4]);

int main(void)
{
    int c, r, sum = 0;
    int s[3][4];  //declared inside the main
    for (r = 0; r <= 2; r++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c <= 3; c++)
        {
            printf("Enter value for s[%d][%d]: ", r, c);
            scanf("%d", &s[r][c]);
        }
    }
    printf("The sum is: %d\n", sumx(s));  //pass to the function because now it is not global;
    return 0;
}

int sumx(int s[3][4])
{
    int sum = 0;  //sum is initialized to zero otherwise it will take garbage value
    for (int r = 0; r <= 2; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c <= 3; c++)
        {
            sum = s[r][c] + sum;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Which standard predefines a function `sum()`?  It isn't the C standard or POSIX, AFAIK.

Comment: @jonathanLeffler there were many problems in the code not only the semicolon.

Comment: @MohitYadav and your answer didn't cover it all

Comment: Please provide a reference to the standard where it specifies a `sum` function. And we are not a "gimme teh correct codez" service. Handling syntax errors and other compiler diagnostics etc. is part of learning how to program. You did not help OP with just providing him code. Btw: You define `sum` yourself in your code, against your initial statement!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a trailing `;` here:

```
int sum(int s[3][4])
```

Comment: Isn't there a "close as typo" reason? Do we really need another "missing semicolon" question?

Comment: @Olaf: Hey, sure enough there is!! I voted to close it, but I'm leaving this answer because it might actually help OP.  Thanks for -1!

Comment: Problem is the question will not [roomba](http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) with an answer under certain circumstances. And delete votes for manual deletion are rare. A comment would have done better here.

Comment: @Olaf: Well that's sort of interesting, I had no idea after being on SO for 8 years.  I guess 99% of users will never read about this "Roomba" thing.

Comment: Yes, there should be some introduction to this once you have a certain rep.

Comment: @Olaf: Or maybe the Roomba should be enhanced to deal with closed questions so that we don't have to learn such minutiae.

Comment: We,, it does deal with closed questions, too. But automatic deletion should not go too far, thus the additional requirements about answers. See the history, there are quite some closed questions with high votes.